# UINavigationBar - How to add an fixed bar on top of navbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to create an iPad app with the following layout :
[image: App Mockup]
 -

- A "Dashboard" : this bar contains extra contents (current step of the
  recipe, timer, etc) and is always displayed on top of the classic
  navbar
- A Navbar : it contains a menu button (sliding menu), a back button, a title and a search field.
- Content zone : content of the current view.

When a new viewController is pushed in the navigationController, I just want the content and the view title to be pushed. Dashboard and navbar background must be static.

What is the best way to achieve this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Dashboard bar as `UINavigationBar` and design a `UIView` for your current NavBar. On navigation, pass the value of "view title" and manage accordingly.